# Initialize dictionary inside dictionary C# vs Python

Tags: python, c#

Why dictionary inside dictionary needs to be explicit in c# e.g. see the following code d1,d2 are fine but on d3 compiler throwing a fit.

```
var d1 = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "1", "1" } }; //works
var d2 = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> { { "1", d1 } }; //works
var d3 = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> { { "1", { { "1", "1" } } }} //does not work
```

Python does same and much simpler way

```
d1:dict={'1':1}
d2:dict = {'1':{'1':1}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've left out the `new Dictionary<string, string>` part (and one closing `}`):

```
var d3 = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> { { "1", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "1", "1" } } } };
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
```

You need to tell C# what concrete instance to create because you could be using a `Dictionary` subclass:

```
class SomeDictionarySubclass<K, V> : Dictionary<K, V> {
    // ...
}
// ...
var d3 = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> {
    { "1", new SomeDictionarySubclass<string, string> { { "1", "1" } } }
};
```

Comment: How nice, new Dictionary<string, string> was missing part other was typo, great Thanks